# ASP.NET Core JWT - what't the difference between HmacSha512 and HmacSha512Signature algorithms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

There're these two similar options in `SecurityAlgorithms` class.
Which one should be used for signing JWT token? Is there any difference?

Comment: Where are you providing the algorithm?

Comment: In the `SigningCredentials` of `SecurityTokenDescriptor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the header of the token and specifically in the `alg` attribute. When you use `HmacSha512` the header looks like this:

```json
{
  "alg": "HS512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

But when you use `HmacSha512Signature` the header looks like this:

```json
{
  "alg": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

You can confirm that using https://jwt.io/.

When I had the same question, I found out that many libraries, mostly outside .NET, do **not** support `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha512` as a valid value for the `alg` attribute because it is not included in the [JSON Web Algorithms RFC, Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1).

**Related discussion 1**: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/662

**Related discussion 2**: https://giters.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/676

So personally I decided to use `HmacSha512`. If your whole system will be developed inside the .NET ecosystem you can use either and they work the same but if the token could be consumed by an application that isn't .NET it's probably better to use `HmacSha512`.

Comment: This was a problem with the .NET implementation, but it doesn't affect .NET Core. See relevant unit tests: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/test/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.Tests/JwtSecurityTokenHandlerTests.cs#L614

Answer (score 1):

There's no functional difference for JWTs; under the hood, `HmacSha512Signature` gets converted to `HmacSha512`.

My limited understanding is that they're different constants that represent the same underlying algorithm. The `Signature` versions are identifiers for representing the algorithm in XML, while the ones without the suffix map to the algorithm identifiers used by JWT.

[Old documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.signingcredentials.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-identitymodel-tokens-signingcredentials-ctor(system-identitymodel-tokens-securitykey-system-string-system-string)) contains a remark on using the algorithms ending in 'Signature' for the signature argument, but the [latest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.signingcredentials.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-signingcredentials-ctor(microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-securitykey-system-string)) no longer contains that remark. I suspect the Signature version was kept around for legacy and backwards compatibility reasons.